# Junction table/many to many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following tables

**Table1:** machinelist

```
machinename       (PK,ncarchar(10),not null)
machine_id        (computed,nvarchar(2),null)
```

**Table2:** JDEPARTIMGLU

```
ndx_jde_part_img  (pk,int,not null)
jde_part_num      (varchar(20)null)
```

- ....(more columns)

I want to create many to many relationship between `machinename` and `jde_part_num`. I think I need to use a junction table to do this. I tried using `machinename` from table1 and `jde_part_num` from table2, but im having issues setting up the FK.

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, can anyone help direct me in the right direction on how to do this?

I will have many parts that are used on many machines and many machines that use the same part

Comment: Yes, you need a third table, but not sure what is your question about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use both PKs on the junction table

```
CREATE TABLE Junction
(
  machinename       nvarchar(10) not null,
  ndx_jde_part_img  int not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (machinename,ndx_jde_part_img),
  CONSTRAINT fk_machines FOREIGN KEY (machinename) REFERENCES machinelist(machinename),
  CONSTRAINT fk_parts FOREIGN KEY (ndx_jde_part_img) REFERENCES JDEPARTIMGLU(ndx_jde_part_img)
);
```

You can even add some new columns to this table, like number of parts needed on that machine.

Comment: Yes this works thank you!, now to learn how to query those table :P

Answer (score 1):

yes, you need a third table `machine_parts`

```
machinename       FK   (machinelist)
ndx_jde_part_img  FK   (JDEPARTIMGLU)
```

So if you have a machine can find all the part it use. And if you have a part can find out which machines need it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add `Machine_ID INT` to the first table as PK and then in the 3rd table just use `Machine_ID INT`, `ndx_jde_part_img INT` and `Quantity DECIMAL`. then build FKs for that table.

Comment: Primary key by up to 20 bytes column is not very good solution. It will slow the process and have extra space for the new table.